# Finding solutions of $x^{201}+x^{21}+x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$?

Tags: modular-arithmetic, congruences

> Find integral solutions of:
>
> $x^{201}+x^{21}+x+1 \equiv 0 \mod 5$.

I know the solution is $3+5n, n \in \mathbb Z $ but I'm trying to work out how to get there.

The big exponents are throwing me off, what is the easiest method? I thought about plugging in the values of $\mod 5$ manually...

Comment: Do you know Fermat's Little Theorem?

Comment: You could just plug in all 5 possible residues. $0,\pm1, 2$. $2$ is the trickiest but you can calculate large powers by finding a pattern.

Comment: @user12002 Please remember that you can choose an answer among the given if the OP is solved, more details here https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work

Answer (score 3):

**HINT**

Note that by FLT

$$x^4\equiv 1 \mod 5$$

then

$$x^{201}+x^{21}+x+1\equiv x+x+x+1 \equiv 3x+1 \mod 5$$